# Issue while attaching PDF content through REST service

Tags: java, rest, pdf, java-7

I am getting an Issue while attaching PDF content to REST services.
REST service response is successful but I am getting empty PDFs while retrieving file from server.

Below code using JSON Content Type to do REST service call and has Basic authentication mechanism.

I am converting PDF to byte array and attaching it in HTTP Body content as string.

Below is my code -

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class AttachPDF {

    static String jsonBody = "{\"property\":\"SAMPLE\",\"propName\":\"SAMPLTEST\"}";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String authStr = "test" + ":" + "xsyq12";

        // encode data on your side using BASE64
        byte[] bytesEncoded = Base64.encodeBase64(authStr.getBytes());
        String authEncoded = new String(bytesEncoded);

        Path pdfPath = Paths.get("E:\\17251897.pdf");
        byte[] pdf = Files.readAllBytes(pdfPath);
        String pdfContent = new String(pdf);

        URL serverUrl = new URL("http://servicesTest.com/attachPDF");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) serverUrl.openConnection();
        String boundaryString = "----WebKitFormBoundary" + Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis());

        // Indicate that we want to write to the HTTP request body
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundaryString);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authEncoded);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");

        // Indicate that we want to write some data as the HTTP request body
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream outputStreamToRequestBody = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter httpRequestBodyWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStreamToRequestBody));

        // Include value from the myFileDescription text area in the post data
        httpRequestBodyWriter.write("\n\n--" + boundaryString + "\n");
        httpRequestBodyWriter.write("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attachSource\"" + "\n");
        httpRequestBodyWriter.write("Content-Type: application/json");
        httpRequestBodyWriter.write("\n\n");
        httpRequestBodyWriter.write(jsonBody);
        // Include the section to describe the file
        httpRequestBodyWriter.write("\n--" + boundaryString + "\n");
        httpRequestBodyWriter.write("Content-Disposition: form-data; " + "name=\"file_input\";filename=\"17251897.pdf\""
                + "\nContent-Type: application/pdf\n\n");
        httpRequestBodyWriter.write("file_input:" + pdfContent);

        httpRequestBodyWriter.flush();

        // Mark the end of the multipart http request
        httpRequestBodyWriter.write("\n--" + boundaryString + "--\n");
        httpRequestBodyWriter.flush();

        // Close the streams
        outputStreamToRequestBody.close();
        httpRequestBodyWriter.close();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }
}
```

[image: Empty PDF Content]

Comment: A pdf is binary data, not textual data. Treating it as a string, therefore,  is likely to damage it.

Comment: oh, What will be the best way to dump binary data in request. pdf var is of type byte array

Comment: The correct way would be to not wrap the `outputStreamToRequestBody` but instead use it as an `OutputStream`. That way writing byte arrays to it remains trivial.